# how can i Create space between two text fname and contact?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to create space between 'fname' and 'contact'. It is displaying in this format :- 1: Mayank , 2: 77177.

But I want to display the text in this format :-

1: Mayank,

2:77177

```
Widget buildResultCard(data) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Card(
          color: Colors.white,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            side: BorderSide(color: Colors.purpleAccent,width: 2),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
              width:150,
              height: 200,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 2.0, bottom: 5.0),
                  child: Row(children: <Widget>[
                    Image.network(data['image'],width: 150, height: 150,fit: BoxFit.cover,),
                    Spacer(),
                  ]),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 10),
              Text(data['fname'], style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0,),),

           // Want to display one next the other.

                Text(data['contact'], style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0,height: 1.5),),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use one of this two options:

1. Wrap your texts in a Column widget.
2. \n Adds an "end of line"

Example (2):

> new Text(':-\n\n${data['fname']},\n\n${data['contact']}')

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Card(
          color: Colors.white,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            side: BorderSide(color: Colors.purpleAccent,width: 2),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  width:150,
                  height: 200,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 2.0, bottom: 5.0),
                  child: Row(children: <Widget>[
                    Image.network(data['image'],width: 150, height: 150,fit: BoxFit.cover,),
                    Spacer(),
                  ]),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 10),
                Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[
                  Text(data['fname'], style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0,),),

                  // Want to display one next the other.

                  Text(data['contact'], style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0,height: 1.5),),
                 ],
                ),

              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

[image]

Comment: I tried to keep the modifing low so it might work for you all I did was to add a column to the text boxes.